The SEDE refresh is stuck on Math
I just happened to check in the SEDE refresh with this query:
select database_id
     , database_name
     , site_name
     , initialized
     , made_available
     , processing_time
     , latest_post
     , notes
from sede_databases
where notes is not null

and got this result:

In the last column you see the UTC time when the refresh for that database started. At the time of posting that is a couple of hours ago. I did notice that all these databases already have refreshed earlier, based on the timestamp in the initialized and made_available columns. I thought that maybe the 'notes' column didn't get cleared properly  but looking at the result of this query:
select *
from sys.databases
where name like '%_Temp'

we learn that the databases are indeed in the process of being updated:

and that is where we find the odd one out. It is Math again.
The Math database does still have its Temp database around, but no longer has a notice. I assume that is the one that got stuck for some reason or another. Note that you can't switch or run queries against the Mathematics database. Trying ends with a Runtime Error.
The fact that the refresh was restarted probably means Aaron or the SRE on call did notice an anomaly earlier on and took action already. I assume they will re-check soon-ish.
This post is a heads-up for anyone that runs a multi-db query or doing their Math and wonders why it fails or why data seems incomplete for some databases.

Perhaps another storm?

Retagging as support for now, as you'd noted in your final paragraph that it's just a heads-up for others. If it continues for a while, feel free to revert.
